# How to parse JSONArray without JSONObject in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have a trouble finding a way how to parse JSONArray in Android. It looks like this:

[70.0,40.0,30.0,20.0,10.0,30.0,90.0]

There is just JSONArray not JSONObject.

Can somebody please help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your values are in a array dataArray.

```
public JSONArray getJsonParam(){
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();

for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++)
jsonArray.put(dataArray[i]);

return jsonArray;
}
```

call `getJsonParam().toString();` where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the JSONArray object:

```
JSONArray j = new JSONArray("[70.0,40.0,30.0,20.0,10.0,30.0,90.0]");
```

with the .get(int i) method you can extract the values

```
System.out.println(j.get(1)); //40
System.out.println(j.get(4)); //10
System.out.println(j.get(6)); //90
```

Comment: Thank you, but my question is not clear sorry for that. I create rest api and my service output is this array, I couldnt write directly JSONArray j = new JSONArray("[70.0,40.0,30.0,20.0,10.0,30.0,90.0]");

Comment: I used AsyncTask then just I need how can parse this array

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is. If your service passes a jsonarray, you can create a (json) string, then add it to the constructor of JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

**You can parse your response as per below code**

```
 JSONArray jsonMainArr = new JSONArray(" your response");
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.length(); i++) {  // **line 2**
         int value= jsonMainArr.getString(i);
       }
```

i hope you will get solution.